# How to pass a List<Interface> and an implemented method from another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parameters, interface

I have a Game Manager, which is used to manage the execution order of specific Unity callbacks (`FixedUpdate`, `Update` and `LateUpdate`) in all the other scripts.

Specifically, I wrote these 3 interfaces:

```
public interface IFixedAt {
    bool IsActive { get; }
    void FixedAt(); 
}

public interface IUpdateAt {
    bool IsActive { get; }
    void UpdateAt();
}

public interface ILateUpdateAt {
    bool IsActive { get; }
    void LateUpdateAt();
}
```

These interfaces are implemented in game objects' scripts, where needed, like this for example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour, IUpdateAt, ILateUpdateAt {

    [SerializeField]
    bool isActive = true;
    public bool IsActive {
        get {
            return (isActive && gameObject.activeInHierarchy);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAt() {
        // Do stuff in Update
    }

    public void LateUpdateAt() {
        // Do stuff in Late Update
    }
}
```

The Game Manager script gets at Awake the reference to all scripts which implement the interfaces, creating a `List<Interface>` and then uses the list at runtime to execute the callbacks only where needed:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<GameObject> GameObjectsWithScripts;
    List<IFixedAt> fixedAtList { get; set; }
    List<IUpdateAt> updateAtList { get; set; }
    List<ILateUpdateAt> lateUpdateAtList { get; set; }

    private void Awake() {
        PopulateAllLists();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {        
        if (fixedAtList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fixedAtList.Count; i++) {
                if (fixedAtList[i].IsActive)
                    fixedAtList[i].FixedAt();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (updateAtList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < updateAtList.Count; i++) {  
                if (updateAtList[i].IsActive)
                    updateAtList[i].UpdateAt();
            }
        }       
    }

    private void LateUpdate() {
        if (lateUpdateAtList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lateUpdateAtList.Count; i++) {
                if (lateUpdateAtList[i].IsActive)
                    lateUpdateAtList[i].LateUpdateAt();
            }
        }
    }

    void PopulateAllLists() {
        fixedAtList = PopulateList<IFixedAt>(GameObjectsWithScripts);
        updateAtList = PopulateList<IUpdateAt>(GameObjectsWithScripts);
        lateUpdateAtList = PopulateList<ILateUpdateAt>(GameObjectsWithScripts);     
    }

    List<T> PopulateList<T> (List<GameObject> goScripts) {
        //Scans the GOs list and adds existent interface elements to the list
        var list = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < goScripts.Count; i++) {
            if (goScripts[i].GetComponent<T>() != null) {
                list.Add(goScripts[i].GetComponent<T>());               
            }           
        }

        //Returns list (null if list is empty)
        if (list.Count > 0) {
            return list;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the question for which I'm having trouble in understanding if it's possible to do, and if yes, how.

As you can see, the code inside `FixedUpdate`, `Update` and `LateUpdate` is basically the same: it iterates on the specific `List`, checks if the current element is active, and if true it executes the proprietary callback.

What I want to know is if it's possible to create a generic method that can be called from inside the three callbacks, and passing to it the `List` to iterate on and the specific method to call for that `List`, something like this in pseudo-code:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {        
    Method (fixedAtList, FixedAt() );
}

private void Update() {        
    Method (updateAtList, UpdateAt() );
}

private void LateUpdate() {        
    Method (lateUpdateAtList, LateUpdateAt() );
}

private void Method<T> (List<T> list, Action method) {
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {  
            if (list[i].IsActive)
                list[i].method();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried different things, to no success, and atm I'm clueless about how to do that. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need an interface that covers the `IsActive` method.

```
public interface IActive {
    bool IsActive { get; }
}

public interface IFixedAt : IActive {
    void FixedAt(); 
}

public interface IUpdateAt : IActive {
    void UpdateAt();
}

public interface ILateUpdateAt : IActive {
    void LateUpdateAt();
}
```

Then you need to use the generic `Action<T>` and then you can pass in lambdas

```
private void FixedUpdate() {        
    Method (fixedAtList, f => f.FixedAt() );
}

private void Update() {        
    Method (updateAtList, u => u.UpdateAt() );
}

private void LateUpdate() {        
    Method (lateUpdateAtList, l => l.LateUpdateAt() );
}

private void Method<T> (List<T> list, Action<T> method) where T : IActive {
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {  
            if (list[i].IsActive)
                method(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is so simple that I feel dumb not having thought of it, thanks. :> BTW, you used `f`, `l` and `u` as the lambdas' parameters just for clarity, right? I can use `x` as the parameter in all three and it works the same, or is there something else behind that choice?

Comment: You have use any parameter names for the lambdas.  I just picked those to match the first letter of the class/method.